# how to lock Iphone by programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flex4

Is there is any option to lock the Iphone by Software Code. Currently I am working in Flex 4 . I couldn't get any idea about this work. actually my Iphone covered by thick panel , it's very difficult to press the lock button . so I planned to create a shortcut for lock Iphone by coding. Kindly give me some Idea about this task, using Flex 4 or other Languages also is okay. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this so, Apple never approve this, your app must be jailbreak. you can do this by calling Private framework on your project. you can use `GraphicsServices.framework`. note , this `GraphicsServices.framework` is a private framework. Apple never accept your app. By calling `GSEventLockDevice()` method you can lock your Iphone Device easily.  This `GSEventLockDevice()` resides in the `GSEvent.h`. hope this one helps .

Comment: Thanks a lot for replay. I have did this already by same way.

Comment: yeah I know, it's little late.

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this using flex or the iOS SDK.  You can, however, enable AssistiveTouch by going into `Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> AssistiveTouch` which will put a little button on your screen that when tapped will allow you to lock your device

Comment: is there is any other ready made software available for this ? is any other lock or pattern lock software have good look and feel gesture ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this on a device that isn't jailbroken- Apple won't let you. Even if you did figure out a way to somehow do this, it would never pass the submission process. If you are developing for jailbroken devices, it's another story, but for the App Store, what you want is impossible.