# Lock Iphone Programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I want to lock my iphone programmatically means i am using app and app has button say local iphone. when i will pass this button, my app will go in background and iphone lock screen will appear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553237/how-to-lock-iphone-by-programmatically

Comment: if u r trying to put htis app on App Store, this is not possible, else google MDM Apple

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-iphone-screen

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this so, Apple never approve this, your app must be **jailbreak**. you can do this by calling Private framework on your project. you can use **GraphicsServices.framework**. note , this **GraphicsServices.framework** is a private framework. Apple never accept your app. By calling **GSEventLockDevice()** method you can lock your Iphone Device easily. This **GSEventLockDevice()** resides in the **GSEvent.h**. hope this one helps .