# Which method is called when device is about to be unlocked?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, cydia, theos

I would like to know where the `-(void)unlock` (or whatever is called) used when we `"slide to unlock"` on the `LockScreen` is.

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I recently released a tweak on Cydia : WelcomeMessage, and there are some issues with people who have passcode enabled. I would like to put my welcoming message after the user types his passcode, and then add a little additional time, in that way the message will be displayed a bit longer than now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these

**iOS 4 - 5**

```
SBAwayController -(void)_finishedUnlockAttemptWithStatus:(char)
```

Argument will be non zero (I don't quite sure it will always be 1 when device is unlocked) when device is about to be unlocked.

**iOS 6**

```
SBAwayController -(void)_finishUnlockWithSound:(char) unlockSource:(int) isAutoUnlock:(char)
```

**iOS 7**

```
SBLockScreenViewController -(void)finishUIUnlockFromSource:(int)
```

Comment: Thanks creker for your response. I will try those and will confirm if they work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use by calling the method  `GSEventLockDevice ();`  from your application, and it can be found in `GraphicsServices.framework.`

From here you can get more idea : [how to lock Iphone by programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553237/how-to-lock-iphone-by-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Divya but that is not what I'm actually looking for. I already saw the post you linked but it doesn't match with my request. I need the (void) called when the user unlocks the device from LockScreen to do `<add my code> %orig;`