# Displaying an UIAlertView When A User Unlocks iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I have recently been having some trouble with iOS 7 and unlocking. I am trying to get an `UIAlertView` to display every time a user unlocks his/her device.

I have gotten the same thing to work with respringing. I am using iOSOpenDev with the logos template. Does anyone know how to achieve an `Alert` right after unlocking with iOS 7's `SBLockscreenViewController`, or with something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877623/which-method-is-called-when-device-is-about-to-be-unlocked/21879327#21879327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these methods from SBLockScreenViewController:

```
-(void) prepareForUIUnlock;
-(void) finishUIUnlockFromSource:(int)source;
```

Both should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me hours more of trying to hunt down the right methods..

Comment: @taysamjiggly, did you read my comment? Your question is already been answered.

Comment: @creker I saw your comment and I tried it, but it left out the (source) part and my tweak was coming up with errors. I figured it out and thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Every time when your application becomes active the following action will be called:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Comment: He is talking about a jailbreak tweak, not an app.